# Reuse LightSwitch built RIA services with alternate UI

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Is it possible to access the RIA services generated by LightSwitch? I'd like to create an HTML interface in addition to the Silverlight one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can but don't because it can cause database locks. I already spent weeks working on it. It is a "unsupported scenerio"

However, see:
Integrating Visual Studio LightSwitch Application Into An Existing Website using IFrames
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/DNNThingsForSale.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  I'd suggest just creating a Dynamic Data website if you want to get a quick-and-dirty CRUD applicaiton up for editing data.

**I know this next statement is an oversimplification, but it's close enough to truth if you don't peer too closely under the hood:**

Lightswitch is pretty much just a port of Dynamic Data web applicaitons for ASP.NET to a WPF applicaiton, with all the plubming hidden.

Comment: The plumbing is not hidden, See the articles on http://LightSwitchHelpWebsite.com